# Subsetting non NA elements from matrix to a vector

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I have a matrix like this:

```
   [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6]
[1]NA   NA   NA    2    NA   NA
[2]NA   NA   NA    7     5   4
[3]NA   2     2    2     2   2
[4]NA   4     4    32    1   1
[5]9   NA    NA   NA     NA   NA
[6]NA  2      1    1     1    1
```

Is there any way to subset (maybe column-wise) the elements which are not NA and then store all numbers in 1 numeric vector, so that I can plot them as.numeric?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need output to be 6 vectors, because there are 6 columns? Or just single vector?

Comment: no, only a single vector

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#dummy data
mat <- matrix(rep(c(1,2,3,NA),7),ncol=4)
mat
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   NA    3    2
# [2,]    2    1   NA    3
# [3,]    3    2    1   NA
# [4,]   NA    3    2    1
# [5,]    1   NA    3    2
# [6,]    2    1   NA    3
# [7,]    3    2    1   NA

mat[!is.na(mat)]
# [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: I just realise that my answer is more or less the same as yours. What's the use of `as.character(.)` here?

Comment: For some reason, I thought I needed to change the matrix to vector :), updated now, thanks. Oops, now our answers look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` and `na.omit`:

```
unlist(apply(mat, 2, na.omit))
# [1]  9  2  4  2  2  4  1  2  7  2 32  1  5  2  1  1  4  2  1  1
```

You can also use

```
na.omit(as.vector(mat))
```

Comment: for which paramter is the 2 in the middle?

Comment: @user3069326 The `2` indicates that the function (`na.omit`) is applied to the second dimension, i.e., the columns.